# AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'FieldType'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Python, flask, and sqlalchemy newbie here. I'm writing a small application to collect data (from excel files) from different groups (departments). Each department will have associated table, with associated fields. Fields will have predefined types (Numeric, Regular Text, Date). My models.py is:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.schema import Sequence, CreateSequence

class FieldType(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'fieldtype'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('ftypeid'), primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    python_type = db.Column(db.String(120))
    python_import = db.Column(db.String(120))

class Field(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'field'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('fieldid'), primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True, unique = True)
    position = db.Column(db.Integer)
    ftype = db.Column(db.FieldType) #The error is happening here.
    tableinfoid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tableinfo.id'))

class TableInfo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tableinfo'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('tinfoid'), primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), index = True, unique = True)
    fields = db.relationship('Field', backref='parent_table', lazy='dynamic')

class Department(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'department'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('dpartmntid'), primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True, unique = True)
```

When I try to run the application, there's an error:

```
(env)[vagrant@localhost dataupload]$ ./run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
from app import theapp
File "/home/vagrant/Development/dataupload/app/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from app import views, models
File "/home/vagrant/Development/dataupload/app/models.py", line 13, in <module>
class Field(db.Model):
File "/home/vagrant/Development/dataupload/app/models.py", line 20, in Field
ftype = db.Column(db.FieldType)     #The error is happening here.
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'FieldType'
```

I'm using my understanding of object oriented design. But I may don't fully understand how sqlalchemy does the mapping - I followed closely from the Flask Mega-Tutorial by Miguel. But I figured I'd start defining the field type and then build on that piece from there. If there's gap in my understanding, please help me fill it so I can accomplish this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't recursively create tables in `SQL` for any database that I know of. so this line

```
ftype = db.Column(db.FieldType)
```

doesn't make any sense given that.

[Without more information I'm going to assume that you want a many to one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952010/many-to-one-relationship-in-sqlalchemy)

```
Column('mtype_id', ForeignKey('FieldType.id'))
```

Is what you actually want in that case. What this allows you to do is to create a reference to a specific instance of `FieldType` with the key to that reference in  a instance of `Field`.

[If you want to be able to have a Field point to many FieldTypes than you'll need a many to many relationship.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174979/sqlalchemy-many-to-many-relationship-on-declarative-tables)

Comment: thanks for your response. It pointed me in the right direction. I also realized that I needed a one to many relationship from fieldtype to field as there will be only three fieldtypes; Text, number, and date. So any number of fields would be exactly one of these types. Again, thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome. Sorry that someone down voted you, this was a perfectly valid question asked from the perspective of someone new to this kind of thing.